# Calibra 2400W Amp sound goes up and down

Tags: audio, hyundai, i20

I jut installed Calibra 2400w amp, a sub and calibra 7" x 10" speakers on 2010 Hyundai i20.

When the car is idling the sounds goes up and down on an amp( seems as if amp cut out) but when the car is off (engine off), sound plays ok, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going to need to install an audio capacitor inline with the power feed to your amp. It seems the voltage is probably fluctuating enough while the engine is running for the amp to not want to play nice. A capacitor will cover for those variations and should allow the sound output to stabilize.

Comment: Probably need a blocking diode as well...

Comment: A cars electrical system can only do so much.

Comment: 2400 watts? Can you still hear?